# Programmatically determine background of image (logos, etc) and make transparent?

Tags: vb.net, image, background, transparency, watermark

I'm attempting to write a solution so that my user's can "watermark" their Images with their Company Logo. I've got the actual watermarking part done and working so now I'm creating the "upload logo" feature so that they can provide me with the Logo they wish to appear watermarked onto their Images.

I'm using VB.NET and this will probably end up in a Web Service that accepts the Logo JPG file, and returns the "altered" Logo. What I need to happen in this Web Service is:

1) Gray-scale the image. Which I have working as well, thanks to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/colormatrix.aspx).

2) Make the background transparent (so the logo looks clean when watermarked onto an image). This is where I'm stuck.

I think for the most part, any logos that are uploaded will have a generic white background but I can't assume that. Is there a way to somehow detect the *background* of an image or the *background colors*, so that I may make *those colors* transparent?

I've downloaded and ran [this project from code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/transpoint/), called Transpoint,  which is pretty much what I need except I won't be able to have this as a stand-alone app. Also, I think this is written in Python which is foreign to me.

So basically what I need is just a way to determine the background on an Image (if that's even possible?) or even just the background colors so that I may make them transparent. Any help/advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Lloyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MusiGenesis (and anyone else who may be interested) here is what I did to (kind of) solve my problem. I basically followed the first half of your idea. I've created a function that will accept a `bitmap`, check each pixel against the first pixel at (0,0) - using a threshold of 10 for each RGB color. For each color within that threshold, the pixel is made transparent. Here is my code, which seems to work alright for the few images I've tried it with:

```
Private Function TransparifyBackground(ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Bitmap

        Dim temp As Color

        Dim background As Color = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0) 'top left will be assumed background color

        For y As Integer = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
            For x As Integer = 0 To bmp.Width - 1

                'get the pixel for this position:
                temp = bmp.GetPixel(x, y)

                If ColorsMatch(background, temp) Then

                    'Make the Alpha value 50 for each pixel, leaving the other colors
                    Dim newColor As New Color
                    newColor = Color.Transparent

                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, newColor)

                End If

            Next
        Next

        Return bmp

    End Function

    Private Function ColorsMatch(ByVal background As Color, ByVal temp As Color) As Boolean

        Dim nThreshold As Integer = 10

        Dim temp_R As Integer = CInt(temp.R)
        Dim temp_G As Integer = CInt(temp.G)
        Dim temp_B As Integer = CInt(temp.B)

        Dim R As Integer = CInt(background.R)
        Dim G As Integer = CInt(background.G)
        Dim B As Integer = CInt(background.B)

        'check the difference of each value against our threshold:
        If ((temp_R - R) < nThreshold) AndAlso ((temp_G - G) < nThreshold) AndAlso ((temp_B < B) < nThreshold) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function
```

Comment: This may not matter if the function is called infrequently (like, *not* 100 times per second), but `SetPixel` and `GetPixel` are incredibly slow. If you find you're having a performance bottleneck because of this, you can speed up pixel-based operations by a couple of orders of magnitude by using the `BitmapData` object returned by the `Bitmap.LockBits` method. There are a ton of posts on SO about using LockBits.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind. For the time being though, the function will only be getting called once at a time so I hope that it does not become an issue.

Comment: The 3 (temp_X - X) statements need to be wrapped in Math.Abs(). Otherwise, a small temp_X and large X will yield a number like -100, which will be made transparent even though it is a drastically different color. You probably didn't notice this if your starting color was black (or white--whichever is (255, 255, 255)).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like reading the upper-left pixel and assuming that that pixel is representative of the background color, and then iterating through the image and setting the alpha value of each matching pixel (matching by color) to 0.

I can pretty much guarantee you, however, that the result will be awful.  For transparency to work properly and look good, the image needs to support partial transparency, such that some pixels are completely transparent whereas some are only partially transparent.  Any algorithm that takes a non-transparent image and sets only one color in the image to fully transparent is going to end up with jagged edges.

Most companies I've ever dealt with have versions of their logos done by professional artists, with smooth, partial transparency.  You'd be much better off just requiring customers to submit a logo with transparency than trying to make a non-transparent image into a transparent one with code.  Sorry, but this just doesn't work.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Actually, please un-select this answer. I'm pretty sure Adobe etc. can do this kind of conversion (where they take an image and render the background transparent, but keep the edges of the image smooth), so if they can do it I'm sure there's at least one algorithm for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would actually work (sorry it's just a description):

Assuming the upper-left corner pixel is the image's background color, you could iterate through each pixel in the image and set the alpha to 0 if the pixel color matches the background color (either exactly or within some threshold color distance).  This would then leave you with an image with a transparent background but jagged edges when you re-draw it on a different-color background.  Also, if the background color is present anywhere *inside* the image itself, it will be turned transparent, which you don't want.

To fix the latter problem, your algorithm should start scanning each row of the image from left to right, and stop when it reaches a non-background color pixel; at this point it should start on the same row and scan right to left until reaching a non-bg pixel.

To fix the edges, you can just blur the alpha values of the bitmap.  Basically, you re-calculate the alpha value of each pixel as the average of 9 pixels (itself and the 8 pixels surrounding it, and *just* the alpha values - not the rgb values).  To prevent sequencing artifacts, you would have a temporary array to store the averaged pixel values, which you would then copy back into the image's alpha values at the end of the process.

Also, there's probably one or more third-party tools that do this (is LEAD Tools still around?).